# How to install Python after SSH into Linux Server?

Tags: python

I created a Python script and added Flask to see if I can create a simple web app that can be used on localhost. After that success, I wanted to host this script on a server so I created a Linux server from CloudBolt and SSH'd into it using Putty. I moved my Python files over to this Linux server. I am trying to install Python3 in the server so that I can run my script but I keep getting the

```
-bash: python: command not found
```

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: Which Linux Distro?

Comment: The linux distro is Red hat

Comment: Redhat dev blog has guides on installing Python3 on [RHEL7](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/08/13/install-python3-rhel/) and [RHEL8](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/11/14/python-in-rhel-8/).  You should use a virtual environment, as directed in these docs, to isolate project dependencies.

Comment: _I am trying to install Python3 in the server_ Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that I was using RedHat and was trying to use `apt` instead of `yum`. My issue has been resolved.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

or maybe you have Python3 installed:

```
> python3 --version
```

Comment: Hmmm. Something doesn't seem right perhaps with my description. I can only run the built in commands for git bash. So I can't run any Linux specific commands like apt-get or anything like that.

Comment: If the distro is RedHat, the package manager is `yum`. Try `yum search python` and `yum install` the approriate package.

Comment: Yup. I am so stupid. I was running apt like I was working with Ubuntu. Thanks Everyone!!!!

Comment: @spriteitup Did you solve it, was that the only issue? If so, please post an answer.